# Python + Selenium Button Click

Tags: python, selenium, button, click

Замучался с помощью Selenium на Python пытаться нажать на кнопку "Load more" на сайте Ethermine:
https://ethermine.org/miners/f74481090e76dae84f1eb7b2f7490290d06e01c1/payouts (рандомная страничка)

Объясните, пожалуйста, какие команды кликают по кнопке "Load more" (см. линк выше), все что смог найти уже перепробовал, не работает =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Самое лучшее в данном варианте.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

# delay = 5
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="/usr/bin/chromedriver")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://ethermine.org/miners/f74481090e76dae84f1eb7b2f7490290d06e01c1/payouts")
# time.sleep(delay)
lolkek = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div[3]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/button')
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", lolkek)
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", lolkek)
```

Comment: У вас это работает? У меня выдает ошибку: selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (839, 4695)

Можете прислать полный пример кода?

Comment: Ошибочка, измените данные в ковычках на 
`'driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div[3]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/button').click()'`

Comment: А вы проверяете работу ответа? У меня все еще ошибка :( --> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (839, 4695) Можете прислать ваш полный код?

Comment: Извини друг, оказыватся на этом сайте замудрили, запилил и проверил. Выше приложил рабочий код

Comment: Да, заработало, ура) Я понял, нужен был execute_script, спасибо!

Comment: Библеотеку time можешь убрать как и закоменченный код. Delay оказался не нужен.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://ethermine.org/miners/f74481090e76dae84f1eb7b2f7490290d06e01c1/payouts")
time.sleep(10)

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='app']/div[3]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/button").click()
```

По идее код ниже должен решить проблему, если нет, то надо больше информации.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://ethermine.org/miners/f74481090e76dae84f1eb7b2f7490290d06e01c1/payouts")

WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='app']/div[3]/main/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/button"))).click()
```

Если всё верно, отметь решение галочкой.

Comment: Не работает, ошибка --> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (599, 4692)

Comment: попробуй использовать второе решение

Comment: Та же ошибка( Там на сайте намудрили, простое решение не поможет) Выше через driver.execute_script решили проблему

Comment: самое интересное, что у меня всё работает

Comment: Так, стоп. Это с моей стороны косяк, да - мой PyCharm запускал старый файл, с первым кодом - все заработало после того, как реально запустил второй код. Сори)) Второй вариант работает! Ты крут) Спасибо

Comment: Поменял драйвер, с Firefox на Chrome, проверить через хром, но работает только на Firefox